# What is this type of pin and tumbler lock, and is it more difficult to pick than a Yale lock?

Tags: lock

I am changing the locks at my house and considering this one, whose craters seem more difficult to pick than a standard yale lock.

[image: Pin and tumbler key]

I include only half the key on purpose.

What is the name of the type of key, and is it more difficult to pick?

Comment: if you are worried about picking you might look into electronic locks, which have a variety of options. One thing to note is that most burglars don't enter through locked doors so it doesn't matter too much what type of lock you have as long as you have a lock

Comment: yale locks come in different qualities, from consumer to commercial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is called a dimple lock, and while no professional this [lock wiki](http://www.lockwiki.com/index.php/Dimple) says

> A **dimple lock is not more secure when compared to traditional pin tumbler locks**, but the untraditional nature of the key makes many dimple locks appear sophisticated.

Comment: obscurity != security

Answer (score 3):

A "dimple" lock (of equivalent quality) would be harder to pick than a traditional vertical pin Yale **for those who are most experienced with the much more common pin tumbler arrangement** that Yale uses in their most common locks.

The dimple lock itself is only harder to pick because they are less common, not necessarily because they are more secure.

For a locksmith (or thief) who has taken the initiative to gather the special and different tools needed for dimple locks, and who has practiced and become experienced with that type of lock... no problem.

Comment: These keys are harder to duplicate and more expensive. +